# React Native build fail Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'm using assembleRelease for getting ready to publish build but i'm getting this error.

> > Configure project :app  Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
> >
> > Configure project :rn-fetch-blob  The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle
> >     5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.
> >
> > Configure project :react-native-onesignal  Configuration 'compile' in project ':react-native-onesignal' is deprecated. Use
> >     'implementation' instead. Configuration 'testCompile' in project
> >     ':react-native-onesignal' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation'
> >     instead.
> >
> > Configure project :react-native-image-crop-picker  Configuration 'compile' in project ':react-native-image-crop-picker' is deprecated.
> >     Use 'implementation' instead.
> >
> > Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets  warning: the transform cache was reset. Loading dependency graph, done. bundle: Writing bundle output
> >     to:
> >     /Users/appfile/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
> >     bundle: Done writing bundle output bundle: Copying 43 asset files
> >     bundle: Done copying assets
>
> /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:70:23-42:
>   AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with
>   value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
>        /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:72:24-39:
>   AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with
>   value '@style/AppTheme').
>        warning: string 'ucrop_error_input_data_is_absent' has no default translation. warning: string 'ucrop_mutate_exception_hint' has no
>   default translation.
>   /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:67:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon'
>   with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
>
> /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml:67:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
>
> > Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED Failed to execute aapt com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
> >     aapt
> >             at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
> >             at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
> >             at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> >             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> >             at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     process /Users/zasetsu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt
> >     with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
> >     /Users/zasetsu/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar -M
> >     /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml
> >     -S /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/appfile/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/res/release/resources-release.ap_
> >     --custom-package com.gnpush.istapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release
> >     --no-version-vectors}
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
> >             at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
> >             ... 50 more Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     process /Users/zasetsu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt
> >     with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I
> >     /Users/zasetsu/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar -M
> >     /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/release/AndroidManifest.xml
> >     -S /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release -m -J /Users/appfile/android/app/build/generated/source/r/release -F /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/res/release/resources-release.ap_
> >     --custom-package com.gnpush.istapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/appfile/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/release
> >     --no-version-vectors}
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
> >             at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
> >             at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
> >             at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
> >     Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Users/zasetsu/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt'' finished
> >     with non-zero exit value 1
> >             at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
> >             at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
> >             ... 9 more
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>
>   > Failed to execute aapt

My build.gradle file ;

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }


      // ADD THIS
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

      // ADD THIS
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you check your assets ?
An error message talks about missed icon `ic_launcher`.
`ic_launcher` is icon app on Android
Checks if you have `mipmap`folders in `res` of your Android app with `ic_launcher` files like on the following screenshot :

[image]

Another error talks about a theme not found :
AppTheme.

You need have a styles.xml file in the `values` folder of `res` folder of your app like on the following screenshot :
[image]